# User 'root' has exceeded the 'max_questions' resource

Tags: mysql, database, database-connection

I receive this error:

```
ERROR 1226 (42000): User 'root' has exceeded the 'max_questions' resource (current value: 4)
```

I can't even change the value in database because of this error. any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change root user properties, e.g. -

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'root'@<'host_name'> WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 100
```

Set 0 to reset limitation.

Comment: Thank you but I still receive this error after executing the command you mentioned: `ERROR 1226 (42000): User 'root' has exceeded the 'max_questions' resource (current value: 4)`

Comment: You must reconnect. Then check applied changes, run `SHOW GRANTS`.

Comment: where to change properties. I'm on a shared server and stuck to same error

Comment: Getting this error after executing your command `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 100' at line 1`

Answer (score 2):

Easy way to fix:

```
User 'root' has exceeded the 'max_questions' resource (current value: 100)
```

**To Fix issue you have to wait 1 hour before you run any of these commands..because the problem is, the max questions are set to a certain number of request per HOUR. If you try to run these commands before the 1 hour is up, these commands will NOT work. So wait 1 Hour..**

*after that 1 hour has already passed then run the following in the terminal in exact order:*

```
* mysql -u root -p

* use mysql

* select user, max_questions from user; 

* update user set max_questions = 0 where user = 'root';

* flush privileges;

* select user, max_questions from user;
```

(If root max questions says '0' then you've fixed it..Now you're done)